# Sqlite loop through all tables

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift3

I'm using swift 3 and I'd like to be able to loop through all the tables in my sqlite database. Is there an easy function to do this? I just want to retrieve the table names.

Comment: you need to fire a sql query to find all table names in db and sql query is not restricted to swift, ovj-c or any other language. You can do it in all.

Comment: The important question is what framework you are using to communicate between swift and sqlite

Comment: pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11.3' this is the pod I'm using the Sqlite.swift framework made by stephencelis https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

Comment: @RichardG how would I write a direct SQL query to get these names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In sqlite database schema is sqlite_master  table. It contains name of all the schema (table, Indexes, Views, etc).

to see a list of the tables in the SQLLite database,  Command is ".tables".
and equivalent SQlite  query to get all table names is :

```
select name   from sqlite_master where type='table'
```

You can use [SQL wrapper class](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift) for swift 3.0 to execute above query and fetch result.